# High Severity Error - root element missing

Tags: mysql

I have had MySQL installed for about 2 months on Windows 10. On start up we get presented with an error that says "High Severity Error - root element missing" followed by another high severity error that displays "Log file path must be defined before calling the WriteToLog method".

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: This question has neither to do with MySQL Workbench nor node.js. Seems rather to be about a general server problem and should hence go to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks  Mike Lischke. hope it will work.

Comment: It is a MySQL problem as the MySQL logo appears on the dialog box where it happens. The dba site discusses the issue here: https://serverfault.com/questions/554869/mysql-startup-error-root-element-missing.